# Facebook android sdk 4.* - How can I get the logged in user E-mail?

Tags: android, facebook

1. I'm trying to get the E-mail from the logged in user after login, because I want to check if the user already got his E-mail on my database.
2. But I don't know how can I get the E-mail. I'm getting the name from the user using getName, I would like to get the user's Email using a similar way.

**My activity code:**

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        info = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.info);
        loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);

        loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
                info.setText(message(profile));

                String userId = loginResult.getAccessToken().getUserId();

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                info.setText("Login attempt cancelled.");
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                info.setText("Login attempt failed.");
            }
        });
    }
```

**On resume**

```
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
    info.setText(message(profile));
}
```

**On activity result**

```
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    private String message(Profile profile) {
        StringBuilder stringBuffer = new StringBuilder();
        if (profile != null) {
            stringBuffer.append("Welcome ").append(profile.getName());
        }
        return stringBuffer.toString();
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to ask for permission to get access to a user email. Try something like this.

```
    List<String> permissions = new ArrayList<String>();
    permissions.add("email");
```

Then see if you can access the email after.

```
String email = profile.getProperty("email").toString();
```

All the best.

Answer (score 0):

For accessing "email", you will have to set the permission for it.

```
//FB Login
loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
loginButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("public_profile", "email"));
```

and then you can access it in onSuccess.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need to do in version 4.2.0 if the Facebook SDK for Android:

```
    GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest( loginResult.getAccessToken(),
            new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted( JSONObject object,  GraphResponse response) {
                    Log.d("onCompleted",object.toString());
                }
            });
    Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
    parameters.putString("fields", "email");
    request.setParameters(parameters);
    request.executeAsync();
```

This code should be placed into the `onSucess()` callback method.